# “detail”: “Method \”GET\“ not allowed.” Error

Tags: django

I am trying to create an article by pulling out data from serializer but i get an error that says 
“detail”: “Method \”GET\“ not allowed.” Error

Why?

**Views.py**

```
class ArticleView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=serializer_data, context=serializer_context,)
            serializer_context = {'request': request }
            serializer_data = request.data.get('article',{})

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'success': True})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'fail':'True'})
        except Exception as e:
                return JsonResponse({'exception':'True'})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from accounts.views import ArticleView

urlpatterns = [

    url('createarticle/', ArticleView.as_view(), name='articlecreate'),
    ]
```

Comment: The error message says that GET is not allowed - make a POST request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified a method for HTTP POST with `def post(self, request, format=None):`, but there is no similar method for HTTP GET, e.g. `def get(self, request, format=None):`. Thus, Django does not accept your request.
All HTTP Methods can be found at [Mozzila's dev docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

I recognize this as Django Rest Framework, and thus recommend you read their tutorials on how to use it, as it is [clearly stated here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/).